# Java ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY Error After MySQL Database Migration from 5.7 to 8.0

Tags: java, mysql

We recently migrated our databases from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0. Before the migration, our Java batch code was working fine. However, after the migration, we had an issue with the line of code `rs.last`, which now throws the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed for a result set of type
> ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.

Here's the code which was throwing error:

```java
ResultSet rs = mysqlMasterDB.executeQuery(historyCheck);
rs.last();
int total = rs.getRow();
rs.beforeFirst();
```

The `executeQuery` method is defined as follows:

```java
public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
    return getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(query);
}
```

To fix this issue, I made the following modifications:

I created a new `executeQuery` function that accepts additional parameters for `ResultSet` type and concurrency:

```java
public ResultSet executeQuery(String query, int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency) throws SQLException, SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
    return getConnection().createStatement(resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency).executeQuery(query);
}
```

Then, I changed the line like this:

```java
ResultSet rs = mysqlMasterDB.executeQuery(historyCheck, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rs.last();
int total = rs.getRow();
rs.beforeFirst();
```

However, I'm not sure whether the issue is related to the upgrade of the `mysql-connector-java` dependency from version 5.1.36 to 8.0.33. Can anyone confirm whether this dependency update might be the cause of the problem, or if there's another potential source for this error?

Comment: Why do you scroll the `ResultSet` to the end in the first place?

Comment: @Kayaman What do you mean? If you're wondering why I wrote 'rs.last' at the start, it's to count the entire result.

Comment: Yeah, counting the resultset size up front is always suspicious. Proper programming would have kept your code working with a forward_only resultset.

Comment: @Kayaman The count of the result is needed at the beginning. Because we are performing some calculations based on the count.

Comment: Even if `rs.last()` still worked, it would be still undesirable. It's an expensive and redundant operation. Add the results to your 'dto' and you'll *know* how many you got. And in any case, you could have used `select count(*)` if absolutely necessary (more efficient ) You could even possibly do your "calculations" in SQL

Comment: Well, if you're returning a `ResultSet` from a method, your code probably has a lot of other quality issues. But the `rs.last()` is a real beginner-flag.

Comment: @g00se The query we are using is something like this: `SELECT COUNT(*), rid FROM rm_info_history WHERE rid IN ('1021878', '1022883', '1025119') GROUP BY rid;` So it's not just about taking the count. We are using the result set after finding the count of the result.

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, But the batch was working fine until the migration. Why would the forward_only result set throwing error now. We did updated the dependency `mysql-connector-java`

Comment: Well, your code was not compatible with `ResultSet.FORWARD_ONLY` to begin with since it doesn't support seeking in the ResultSet. Your code worked _by accident_ and after updates you're seeing what should have happened before already. But based on some eariler related questions, I assume MySQL loaded the full ResultSet and allowed you to seek in it *even with*  a `FORWARD_ONLY` hint. Maybe there was a bugfix in some version of the driver and now it behaves correctly.

Comment: E.g. some smart, handsome devil here is talking about MySQL details wrt ResultSets https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162192/2541560

Comment: IIRC, MySQL Connector/J silently upgraded to SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, which is allowed by the JDBC specification.

Comment: *@g00se The query we are using is something like this:...* So, your row count is in range 0 thru 3 and your 'dto' list needs a capacity of 3. I don't see the need to know the count in advance

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So you're saying, it worked before because it was silently upgraded to the  SCROLL_INSENSITIVE?. Could you please share which part of the specification mentioned about it.

Comment: JDBC 4.3, section 15.1.1 "ResultSet Types" allows a result set to use a different result set type if it can't honour the requested type. That said, it is entirely possible that MySQL reported it incorrectly as TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, but had it behave as a TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE; older versions of MySQL Connector/J did not always adhere to the specification.